# making a function càdlàg

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ has a right limit $f(x+)$ at all $a \le x \lt b$ and a left limit $f(x-)$ at all $a\lt x\le b$.

Is the function $$g[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}f(x+)&a\le x\lt b\\ f(b)&x=b\end{cases}$$ [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)? and is the set $\lbrace x\in[a,b]:f(x)\neq g(x)\rbrace$ at most countable (like you would expect)?

Comment: There is a result which says that for any real function there exist only countably
many points $x$ of $\mathbb R$ for which $f$ is not continuous at $x$ but $f(x+)$ exists.
See e.g. van Rooij, Schikhof: A Second Course on Real Functions, Theorem 7.7, [p.45](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false). 
I believe this answers the second part of your question.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I think that to show that the first part is true, it suffices to show that $f(x+)=g(x+)$ and $f(x-)=g(x-)$ for each $x$, which does not seem to be that difficult.

Comment: If these two accounts [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/30027/martin-gale) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/26471/martin-gale) both belong to you, you might consider registering and [ask moderators](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/merging-of-accounts) to [merge](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/how-can-i-participate-in-the-discussion-of-my-question-if-i-lost-the-unregistere) the old accounts with the new one. Registering might make easier for you to follow the questions you posted.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}$ I'll try to give an $\ve$-$\delta$ proof.

You assume that $f(x+)$ exists for each $x$.
You have defined
$$g[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}f(x+)&a\le x\lt b\\ f(b)&x=b\end{cases}$$
and you're asking whether at each point both one-sided limits $g(x-)$ and $g(x+)$ exist and whether $g(x+)=g(x)$.

Clearly, if we show that $f(x+)=g(x+)$ and $f(x-)=g(x-)$, then this is true.

Fix a point $x_0\in[a,b)$

Let $r=f(x_0+)$, i.e. for each $\ve>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-r|<\ve$ for each $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)$. This clearly implies that
$|g(x)-r|=|f(x+)-r|\le\ve$ for each $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta/2)$. This shows that $g(x_0+)=r=f(x_0+)$.

---

Let $l=f(x_0-)$, i.e. for each $\ve>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-l|<\ve$ for each $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0)$. Now if $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0)$ then we have an interval $(x,x_0)$ on the right from $x$ such that $|f(x')-l|<\ve$ for each $x'$ in this interval. From this we get $|g(x)-l|=|f(x+)-l|\le\ve$ for each $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0)$. This shows that $g(x_0-)=l=f(x_0-)$

---

There is a result which says that for any real function there exist only countably
many points $x$ of $\mathbb R$ for which $f$ is not continuous at $x$ but $f(x+)$ exists.
See e.g. van Rooij, Schikhof: A Second Course on Real Functions,
Theorem 7.7, [p.45](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Clearly $f(x)\ne g(x)=f(x+)$ implies that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. By the above result, there is only countably many such points.

Answer (score 0):

By result that Martin said $g $ is continuous except at a contable set $C$ and in $[a,b) \backslash C, \ g(t) = f^{+}(t) = f^{-}(t)= f(t) $ . Hence in $C$, $g$ is càdlàgle se $t \in C \backslash \{b\} .$ By $C$ to be contable, $t$ is a accumulation point and
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(t^{+}) & = & \lim_{s \downarrow t} g(s)\\
& = & \lim_{s \downarrow t} f^{+}(s)\\
& = & \lim_{s\downarrow t} f(s)\\
& = & f(t^{+}) \\
& = & g(t)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Analogously, $g(t^{-})$ exist and is equals to $f(t^{-})$. Hence $g$ is càdlàg. Excuse my bad English.